# How can I modify the Exception Handling values from Web.config

Tags: c#, exception, enterprise-library

I'm starting to use the Exception Handling, in my case I use the configuration manager, creating a Null Policie with a Replace Handler, in this case the message that replace to this exception is the next:"Exists some null values: "...my web.config:

```
<exceptionHandling>
    <exceptionPolicies>
      <add name="Null Policies">
        <exceptionTypes>
          <add name="All Exceptions" type="System.Exception, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
            postHandlingAction="ThrowNewException">
            <exceptionHandlers>
              <add name="Replace Handler" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ReplaceHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                exceptionMessage="Exists some null values" replaceExceptionType="System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </exceptionHandlers>
          </add>
        </exceptionTypes>
      </add>
    </exceptionPolicies>
  </exceptionHandling>
```

In a piece of my code that I know that throw a `NullReferenceException` I want to add the value that throws this exception, and append to the message previous implemented on the configuration:

```
try
 {
    string theValue = anotherThing //this piece of code throw a NullReferenceException 
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {
    if (exManager.HandleException(ex,"Null Policies")) throw; //add 'theValue' to the new Exception
    return "";
 }
```

Researching I found about the `Configuration` class to access to the web.config...and I don't know how to access to this particular piece of the XML -> `exceptionPolicies`<- and modify the property like: exceptionMessage= "Exists some null values "+ theValue;

Hope you can help me...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you have to use the approach you describe? If all you want to do is to add additional information regarding the exception, you can do that by creating and throwing a new exception, specifying the original exception as the inner exception. E.g. in your catch, 'throw new Exception("There were null values - " + someOtherInfo, ex);'. The original exception, and its stacktrace would then be available through the InnerException property of the exception you threw.

Comment: You should not be "handling" NullReferenceException. You should be fixing your bugs that cause it.